# What does "./" (single period) means in html (e.g. <script src="./src/main.js"></script>) for file paths?

Tags: html, path

[image]

`"../"` - two period (e.g.,  `src="../picture.jpg"`) means go up one folder.

`"folder/"` - (e.g., `src="myfolder/picture.jpg"` means go down to `myfolder`folder.

But I saw this single period "./src": `<script src="./src/main.js"></script>` on youtube. I was wondering what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tldr: It's the current working directory and you can omit it in most cases

Lets say your folder structure looks like this:

```
myproject
  src
    main.js
    whatever.js
  index.html
```

Then it actually looks like this because of two hidden "files":

```
myproject
  .
  ..
  src
    .
    ..
    main.js
    whatever.js
  index.html
```

Where `..` is a reference to the folder that is above the current working  directory (if the working directory is `src`, then `../` references `myproject`) and `.` referencing the current working directory itself (If you're in myproject and want to access index.html you could specify it as just `index.html` or `./index.html`). In most cases, you don't need to specify the `.` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, `./` is used to indicate the current directory or folder.

In `<script src="./src/main.js"></script>` the `./` before `src` indicates that the file `main.js` is located in the same directory as the HTML file is. It's not necessary to put them before the file's name.